# mysql group_concat returns garbage integers values on centos server

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mysql-workbench, loopback

I am using this **group_concat** function in mysql stored procedure to concatenate integer value.
group_concat(DISTINCT column_name separator ', ')

It is working fine on **windows** machine but when I am seeing the output of this on **centos(linux) server** via web service (that only returns the out of stored procedure not doing any other processing) its returning some garbage integers value. Those values does not exist in any of my table in database. in all stored procedure its behaving the same way.

Could you Please help me out why this is happening on centos(linux) server.

Comment: Can you add your code in the question?

Comment: SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT Result.PatientId) as PatientCount,
    group_concat(DISTINCT Result.PatientId separator ', ') as AdversePatients
    From 
 adverse_event_form where PatientId in ( SELECT pt.PatientId FROM patient pt where pt.Active=TRUE and pt.DoctorId=doctor_id);

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem solved.

I have cast integer column to char in group_concat, then after it returns the expected output otherwise it return the ascii value of all characters in centos  server  loopback with mysql.